# Looping through object with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, loops

My first time touching JSON and I'm having an issue iterating through the object.

The JSON is formatted as such:

```
{
    "response": {
        "2012-01-01": {
            "Available": 99,
            "Variations": [
                {
                    "ID": 43,
                    "InternalItemID": "Adult",
                    "Price": "49.00"
                }
            ]
        },
        "2012-01-02": {
            "Available": 99,
            "Variations": [
                {
                    "ID": 43,
                    "InternalItemID": "Adult",
                    "Price": "49.00"
                }
            ]
        }
   }
}
```

I am able to access the dates, but cannot get any deeper. I need all the values:

```
$.getJSON(jsonurl, function(data){


            $.each(data.response, function(thisDate){
                alert(thisDate);
            });
        });
```

Can some point me in the right direction please

Comment: You don't really have an issue with *parsing* the JSON string, do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $.each(data.response, function(index,item){
            alert(item.Available);
            var child=item.Variations;
            alert(child[0].Price);
    });
});
```

Working sample http://jsfiddle.net/d84nj/10/

Comment: Just what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[`$.each`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.each) passes the value of each key as the second parameter to the callback.

```
$.each(data.response, function(date, value) {
    // value.Available
});
```

Comment: Was unaware of this, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are working with the property name, when you need the value.

`jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )`

So the reason you can see the date is that it is the property name. You want:

```
$.each(data.response, function(thisDate, valueOfElement){
    alert(thisDate, valueOfElement);
});
```